# Downgrade OpenGL ES 3.x to ES 2

Tags: opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

```
$ glxinfo | grep 'version'

server glx version string: 1.4
client glx version string: 1.4
GLX version: 1.4
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.82
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL version string: 4.5.0 NVIDIA 375.82
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50 NVIDIA
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 NVIDIA 375.82
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
    GL_EXT_shader_implicit_conversions, GL_EXT_shader_integer_mix,
```

How can I change OpenGL ES profile to use version 2?

I tried install `libcogl-gles2-dev` and `libgles2-mesa-dev`. But the version used is stll ES 3.20.

Comment: You can always set your OGL-ES version in the shaders.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of development, OpenGL ES 3.2 is [backwards compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenGL_ES#OpenGL_ES_3.0) with OpenGL ES 2.0, so there isn't a practical reason to downgrade. If you want to support OpenGL ES 2.0 at a minimum, simply only use features that it supports.

If you're insisting on downgrading, you would have to install a (very) old driver that didn't support OpenGL ES 3.0. Depending on your hardware, such a driver may not exist. From the output, you obviously have an Nvidia card - you can find [older drivers here](http://www.nvidia.ca/object/linux-display-archive.html). OpenGL ES 3.0 was released in August 2012, so anything dated before that likely doesn't have support for it. Again, I wouldn't recommend doing this.

Comment: Noted on this. I thought it my driver wont support ES 2.0.